# Finite strings of integers from $\{1,1,2,2,\ldots,n,n\}$ such that there are $k$ elements between the two $k$s

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, modular-arithmetic

A friend was recently posed with the following interview questions.

> 1. Write a string of six elements containing two $1$s, two $2$s, and two $3$s such that between the two appearances of the '$k$' elements, there are exactly $k$ other elements.
> 2. Do the same but with $\{1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4\}$.
> 3. Show that this cannot be done for $\{1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5\}$.

The first two are rather simple and it just requires playing around with different arrangements. The unique (up to reflection) solution for the first is given by $312132$, and for the second we have $41312432$. The third question is interesting because it has the following elegant (non brute-forced) solution.

**Proof**. Assign the value of the position of each element to that element. So for example if $x_3$ is the leftmost $3$-element and it is found in the second position then set $x_3=2$. We note that if $x_k=a$, then the rightmost $k$-element $y_k$ will be $k+1$ positions to the right and so $y_k=a+k+1$. If we take the sum of all $x_k$ and $y_k$ then we find that $$\sum_{k=1}^{5} x_k+y_k = \sum_{k=1}^{5} 2x_k+k+1 = (2\sum_{k=1}^{5} x_k)+20$$ which is even, but also $$\sum_{k=1}^{5} x_k+y_k = \sum_{i=1}^{10} i = 55$$

which is odd. So we reach a contradiction. $\square$

One quickly finds that this same argument extends to all $n$ which are congruent to $1$ or $2$ modulo $4$ (because the contradiction is reached whenever $\sum_{i=1}^{2n} i\neq \sum_{i=1}^n n+1\mod 2$).

My question is, what happens in the other cases. Can this be done for any $n\geq 7$? If so, for how many $n$?

Comment: Related: I put [a CW post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/960609/3111) together for a now-closed Question about these finite sequences.  These are called Langford sequences.

Comment: Ah brilliant. The article of Roy O. Davies that you cite appears to answer the problem then. A solution exists if and only if $n=0,3\mod 4$. Do you happen to know if an online version of the article exists? If not, do you happen to know Davies' (or some other) proof?

Comment: The argument is apparently pretty simple (once you see it!), but I may have to make a trip to the university library to get Davies' original paper.

Comment: @hardmath: He simply gives a scheme for each case. I’ve added the two schemes to your CW post.

Comment: The 1959 Mathematical Gazette articles by C.J. Priday and by Roy O. Davies form [a single entry](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3610650) in the JSTOR online catalog, which one may be able to read without cost through the 3-on-shelf allowance of their [MyJSTOR program](http://www.jstor.org/).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:  Thanks, I'd written the above Comment linking to the articles and failed to click the submit button!

Comment: Thank you both for the links and also transcription of the solution in the other question. It's rather surprising how much attention this problem received in the past and there still seem to be many open questions about $L(2,n)$. If someone wants to collect this into an answer I'd be happy to accept it.